# Reading text that is embedded in a PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a PDF that has a string that is in the catalog portion of the PDF file. I need to read that string. 
With iTextSharp 5 I was able to read the catalog and pull out the string.

I am now limited to another library (Syncfusion) and in that library the catalog is  marked as private and I do not have access to it.

I am able to "open" the PDF in Notepad++ and I can see the string as plain text. I need to programatically open that file and retrieve that string. Using ReadAllBytes  I can read the file but then am at a loss as to how to search it for a specific string.

Any suggestions or examples that I can explore would be appreciated.

Comment: What specific string is it? You can convert the bytes to a string if you know the encoding (eg. ASCII) and then use a Regex to find what you need.

Comment: @LarryTang The string is actually an XML string that is embedded in the PDF. It would be very easy to use Regex to find the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Isn't this the documentation you need? https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text-extraction

Comment: `ExtractText` extracts text content; stuff that is shown on-screen. It sounds like John wants to parse the Catalog metadata; which is not shown on-screen. This is a difficult problem because you have to parse the PDF; a text scan is not going to work. Use a PDF parser that gives you access to the Catalog metadata.

Comment: *"in that library the catalog is marked as private"* - have you tried reflection to access it nonetheless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the encoding of the text, you could always convert the raw bytes to a string and then use a Regex to find what you need.

Here's an example of that:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("example.pdf");
string pdfStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); //for UTF8

Regex pdfReg = new Regex(...); //the regex for finding your string
string pdfSubstring = pdfReg.Match(pdfStr); //the string you needed
```

[C# Regex Reference](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Comment: PDFs are binary, not UTF8. Any byte sequence is legal in a PDF; including invalid UTF8 or multiple occurrences of the target string as data. If @John is searching for characters in the PDF catalog he has to parse the Catalog, not blindly read the entire file.

Comment: I know PDFs aren't UTF, it was a placeholder for encoding, this is more of a hack/workaround to detect the text within the PDF binary. I admit, not an elegant solution.

Comment: @DourHighArch Using the libraries I am restricted to the Catalog is marked as private. I understand that the proposed solution is a hack.